# Where do I set defaults for an associated entity in an embedded Symfony2 form?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity with a OneToOne association to another entity.  For these purposes I'll call the initial entity "Parent" and the associated Entity "Child".

I have a Parent form working fine that embeds the child form and all the form elements for both entities appear, and I can save the data fine in the controller.

Now I want to set defaults for a number of attributes in the embedded doctrine entity.  I could set values for the new entity in the controller, but the child entity is created in the embedded form class:

```
// Parent form
class Parent extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
         //parent->add(...) 
         $builder->add('child', new Child(), array());
    }

// In Child Form
class Child extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('visibilitycode', 'entity', array('label' => 'Visibility', 'class'=>'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Visibility', 'property'=>'name'));
        public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
        {
            return array(
                'data_class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Child',
            );
        }
```

Many of these defaults are for associated foreign keys, so if I was setting them in the controller I might use something like this:

```
$child->setVisibilityCode($em->getReference('AcmeMybundle:Visibility', 'P'));
```

Comment: I think you can create the $child in the controller, set the value then add it to the $parent and then use it to create the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions are offered to you (or maybe more :-) ):

- initialize default values in `Child` entity itself ( in constructor for example)
- use the `empty_data` option of the Form component:

  ```
  class Child extends AbstractType {
  public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
  {

      $builder->add('visibilitycode', 'entity', array(
          'label' => 'Visibility', 
          'class'=>'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Visibility',
          'property'=>'name'
      ));
      public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
      {
          return array(
              'data_class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Child',
              'empty_data' => function() use($visibility) {
                  $child = new Child();
                  $child->setVisibility($visibility);
                  return $child;
              }
          );
       }
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks for your advice on this.  After thinking about it and trying some things I went with option 1, and intialized things in doctrine.  This was better for me for my current use case, because I have some behavior shared across multiple controllers, that doesn't always have a form associated with it.  With that said I hope to try out your 2nd suggestion, as this might be of use in other cases.